# Prolog: Parsing a term for semantic correctness (pattern matching)

Tags: list, parsing, prolog, pattern-matching

I am working on an assignment and I am woefully stuck. I have little experience with prolog and I am learning on the job based on online material and a textbook.

The aim of the assignment is to produce a predicate, parse(), that is able to check that a given argument/term is of the following form, returning true or false as appropriate:

- ((int,int),[(int,float),(int,float)...])

So an int pair, followed by an n-sized list of (int,float) pairs, with both wrapped up in a tuple.

For example:

- ( (1, 7), [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.7), (4, 0.8), (5, 0.8), (6,
  0.25), (7, 0.3)] )

Could anyone point me in the right direction for where to begin on this? I haven't ever done this sort of this in Prolog.

I am not looking for a full coded answer, naturally this is an assignment, but just some direction for how to approach this problem. I have no declarative programming background, so this is an educational exercise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start with the observation that what you show is **already a valid Prolog term**:

```
?- T = ( (1, 7), [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.7), (4, 0.8), (5, 0.8), (6, 0.25), (7, 0.3)] ) .
T =  ((1, 7), [(1, 0.0),  (2, 0.5),  (3, 0.7),  (4, 0.8),  (5, 0.8),  (6, 0.25),  (7, 0.3)]).
```

So, in such a case, there is no manual **parsing** necessary. By *parsing*, we typically mean the conversion of *unstructured* text, such as plain *lists* of characters or character codes, to a **structured** representation.

Prolog *automatically* rejects terms that are not *syntactically* valid. So, in your case, *if* you already have such a term, all it takes is to state what must *hold* about it so that it satisfies all constraints.

In Prolog, it is often useful to first think about **building blocks** you may want to use as a useful basis. For example, let us describe an `(int,float)` term:

```
integer_float_tuple((I,F)) :- integer(I), float(F).
```

We can use it as follows:

```
?- integer_float_tuple((3,4.5)).
true.
```

Note though:

1. First, the definition is *not* a true relation. For example, the most general query `?- integer_float_tuple(T).` will *fail* even though there clearly *are* solutions!
2. Second, using terms of the form `(A,B)` is discouraged, also because `(',')/2` is already used for so many other things in Prolog. It would be better to represent such pairs as `I-F`, using `(-)/2` which is commonly used to denote **pairs** throughout Prolog libraries.

In any case, we can build on this definition with:

```
good_term((Tuple,Tuples)) :-
        Tuple = (A,B),
        integer(A), integer(B),
        maplist(integer_float_tuple, Tuple).
```

This states everything that must hold for such terms, and thus lets you **validate** them although, as noted, not *generate* them. To *generalize* such predicates to work in all directions, use your Prolog system's CLP(FD) and CLP(R) **constraints**. This will give you a definition that is **monotonic** and satisfies many desirable properties we expect from a logic program.

---

Further, *if* you really want to *parse* your data manually (as opposed to relying on Prolog's built-in notion of structured terms), I have two recommendations:

First, add the following directive to your program:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

This lets you conveniently write lists of *characters* with double quotes.

For example:

```
?- Cs = "abc".
Cs = [a, b, c].
```

Such a representation is very convenient for what we do next, which is using Prolog **Definite Clause Grammars** for *parsing* such lists of characters.

I won't solve the whole task for you, but I give you a start. We can start by describing what we mean by a *digit*:

```
digit(D) --> [D], { char_type(D, digit) }.
```

We use such a grammar with the `phrase/2` interface predicate. For example:

```
?- phrase(digit(D), "5").
D = '5'.
```

Building on this definition, let us describe *lists* of digits:

```
digits([]) --> [].
digits([D|Ds]) --> digit(D), digits(Ds).
```

Example query:

```
?- phrase(digits(Ds), "5235").
Ds = ['5', '2', '3', '5'] ;
false.
```

Finally, let us combine all this to decsribe an **integer**:

```
integer(I) --> digit(D), digits(Ds), { number_chars(I, [D|Ds]) }.
```

With `number_chars/2`, we are performing the crucial conversion between *characters* and actual *integers*, which you need in your own representation.

Example query:

```
?- phrase(integer(I), "5235").
I = 5235 ;
false.
```

Using such building blocks, you can conveniently describe the general **outline** of such lists of characters by forther grammar elements.

Overall, your eventual grammar may look like:

```
pattern --> "(", whitespace, "(", integer, ",", integer, ")", ...
```

Where you need to supply definitions for `whitespace//0` and complete the whole description.

See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information about this approach.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful! I've looked into the topics you've discussed and I have managed to get a working solution for my problem (and learnt a bunch of Prolog along the way).

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog we write *predicates*, not functions, that in the most basic case just qualify the 'trueness' of the relation - conventionally described by the 'name' of the predicate, so called *functor* - among the arguments.

So, you're writing a relation among **3** arguments:

```
parse(Needle, Haystack, Found) :-
   ...
```

You should write down a further relation, that holds true when `Needle` matches **one** of the elements of `Haystack`. So you have a choice: either a recursive parse/3, where the current element to be matched is made explicit in the head pattern (that is, `parse(Needle, [Element|Haystack], Found) :- etc`)  or use [member](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)/2 from library(lists), that *on backtracking* will iterate elements...

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! I looked into searching list and tried to understand backtracking. Cheers